# How to upgrade neo4j from 2.3.1 to 3.0.7 with 0 downtime

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ha

I have production server running on 2.3.1 on HA and i wanted to upgrade the version to 3.0.7 with out any downtime. I can create additional server with latest version and restore the backup from 2.3.1 to 3.0.7  but the challenge for me  is, i will lose all the data during the migration time frame  (  while running the re-deployment of API pointing to new server ). I really appreciate if any one have idea on how i can accomplish this with out having downtime on my production environment. Currently server is configured as HA and its pointed to application  via  LB

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Safest bet is something like:

- do full backup
- pause write load
- do incremental backup (should be quick compared to previous full backup)
- start a new cluster on 3.0.7, start with one instance on the backup-db, which will migrate the db from 2.3.1 --> 3.0.7
- start the other instances of the new 3.0.7 cluster, which will copy the db from the 3.0.7 master. (do this asynchronically, don't wait for them to complete the copy).
- redirect all load to new cluster
- resume write load

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. on your step 2  "pause write load",  this means we have downtime correct ?

Comment: Sure although a matter of definition, reads will still be available

Comment: Is there any way that we can find the Delta, like mysql ?